# Hiding files from public folder and css file not being recognized

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am making a webapp:frontend in Angular and backend in Rails.
I have decoupled frontend and backend.

Qestion 1: All my html and javascript files are in public folder right now. Here are paths.

```
html path: root/public/html/..
javascript path: root/public/javascript/..
```

The problem I'm facing right now is that I make all my http requests in javascript files and anyone can see it since it is in public folder. I'm wondering what is the best practice to hide my javascript files. Is it just easy as taking out from the public folder and putting it outside of public folder scope?

Question2: 
I'm using font-awesome. I was using CDN previously but I decided to download the css and use it locally. I have put into my project in following path: `root/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css`
However, It was not displaying icons successfully. So I did a test. I put the css file in `root/public/css/font-awesome.css` and it starts displaying the icons. Do you know why the css file is not being read?

Thanks.

Comment: How would pages load these files if they weren't accessible? You can't prevent access to js or css files...period

Comment: @charlietfl I was thinking about locating them on rootscope of my rails app. Is it not possible?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Whatever it is you are leaning towards creating bigger ones

Comment: There is an edge case that I cannot limit user's access to one of  http requests I'm making. Using Rails' gem, cancancan, I manage to cover most of them but there is one I cannot cover for some reason. So I was thinking of locating javascript in other directory to hide it. But I guess it does not work that way.

Comment: But you are probably talking about blocking content...don't see how blocking js or css would help

Comment: However nothing says those files have to be delivered from the static file directly. A `<script>` tag can point at a dynamic language server script end point that delivers the file contents

Comment: Hiding the Javascript in another location or dynamic route won't help. Anything that is executed on the browser can be easily read with development tools.

Comment: @ollpu yeah I know. But I would want to hide it at least so newbie hackers can't do anything. Maybe I'm overthinking.